# ActionScript 3.0 list listener?

Tags: actionscript-3

In ActionScript 3.0, I have code that displays a list. When a row is selected, how do I add a listener to execute code and how do I extract the position of the selected row

Comment: You should provide some of your code to show how exactly your list is built and displayed - otherwise you probably won't get helpful answers.

Comment: guessing it's a flash List component. try list.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,function(event:Event):void{trace(list.selectedIndex});

Answer (score 0):

If it's an MX list:

To add the event listener:

```
list.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_CLICK, onListItemClick);
```

To get the selected row:

```
public function onListItemClick(le:ListEvent):void
{
  var selectedItem:int = le.rowIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's a FL list:

To add the event listener:

```
list.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onListItemChange);
```

To get the selected row:

```
public function onListItemChange(e:Event):void
{
  var selectedIndex:int = list.selectedIndex;
}
```